# Can I custom edit WordPress image pages?

Tags: html, mysql, wordpress

When I upload images to WordPress I have the ability to click "View" when hovering over those images. This takes me to a permalinked page with the image title as the url and it uses the default post format.

These image pages don't appear on posts, or even pages. They seem to be intrinsically attached to the image. I can't seem to customise each page separately because they just grab the default post format that my theme provides and there's no way to actually access the pages.

I've searched around in my hosting panel but can't find anything. The images are there, the default post type is there, but nothing that is editable. The images have unique URL's so I assume they have to be stored somewhere. Is there a way to manually access each image page?

Answer (score 2):

Create attachment.php in your template page, and change how you want
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/attachment-template-files